# iphone app submission errors

Tags: iphone, app-store

When I try to add my application, I get

> Info.plist does not contain a
>   CFBundleResourceSpecification

and

> Application failed codesign
>   verification. The signature was
>   invalid, or it was not signed with an
>   Apple submission certificate.

I don't understand! I'm so frustrated, I finished my two apps and now I can't submit them.
I checked the provisioning licenses and app ids and that whole process a many times over, I dunno what I'm doing wrong here.

Can anyone help? :(

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but did you get the application being submitted out of build/Release-iphoneos or similar folder?  It sounds like you grabbed the simulator version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional info:

[Apple's word on submitting simulator version by accident](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2009/qa1524.html)